# DateTime is not binded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

ViewModel:

```
public class HistoryViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? OperationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new HistoryViewModel()
    {
        OperationDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HistoryViewModel vm)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View:

```
@model CBH.ViewModels.HistoryViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "BankHistories", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SearchForm" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OperationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Class = "input-small"} })
    <input type="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Now after submitting form `vm.OperationDate` is set to `null`. Other properties are binded correctly, but `DateTime` seems to fail.

- I tried to add `DataType` to my ViewModel
- I tried to submitting dates like "01.01.1990" and "1990.01.01"
- I tried to add type to my `EditorFor`

None of which worked. If I print all `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()` I am getting:

```
dd.MM.yyyy
d MMM yyyy
dddd, d MMMM yyyy
d MMMM yyyy
dddd, d MMMM yyyy HH:mm
d MMMM yyyy HH:mm
dddd, d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm
d MMM yyyy HH:mm
dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss
d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
d MMMM
d MMMM
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
HH:mm
HH:mm:ss
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
dddd, d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM yyyy
MMMM yyyy
```

Comment: If you are using chrome its applies US date format

Comment: Add [DataType(DataType.Date)] to your model field

Comment: @mbadeveloper Unfortunelly none of your tips worked.

Comment: Ok use @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OperationDate , "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")

Comment: @mbadeveloper oh I found out that I was setting `name` property. Without that it is working properly with `EditorFor` and `TextBoxFor`. Thanks for help :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP resolved the problem, and now this question will not receive an answer.